# Child component in Vue 3 is not updated

Tags: vuejs3, vue-component, reactive-programming

My app has a parent component that receives data after an API call and passes it to the child component (`DropDown`):

```
import { computed, onMounted } from 'vue';
import defaultService from '@/services/defaultService';
import ProductCard from '@/components/ProductCard.vue';
import DropDown from '@/components/DropDown.vue';

const [filter1, filter2, filter3, filter4] = ["Can be used for", "Product category", "Used on project", "Supplier"];

let categoriesAndAppTypes: any = {};
const selects: Record<string, string[]> = {
  [filter1]: [],
  [filter2]: [],
  [filter3]: [],
  [filter4]: []
};

const getCategories = (data: any): void => {
  categoriesAndAppTypes = data;
  selects[filter1] = Object.keys(data);
  selects[filter2] = Object.values<string[]>(data).flat();
  selects[filter3] = ['Project 1', 'Project 2', 'Project 3', 'Project 4'];
  selects[filter4] = ['Supplier 1', 'Supplier 2', 'Supplier 3', 'Supplier 4'];
  console.log({ categoriesAndAppTypes, selects });
};

onMounted(() => {
  defaultService.getDataJson(getCategories, 'categories');
});

const computedSelects = computed(() => selects)

</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <ProductCard></ProductCard>
  </div>
  <section>
    <DropDown :data="[filter1, computedSelects[filter1]]" />
  </section>
</template>
```

The problem is that the child component doesn't receive `computedSelects[filter1]]`, although it should be an Array. I.e. it doesn't get updated when real data gets in the place.

Child is like this:

```
<template>
  <menu ref="menuSelect" class="select" @click="manageSelect">
    <div class="menu-header">{{ data?.[0] }}</div>
    <div class="pointer"></div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="label in data?.[1]">
        <a href="#">{{ label }}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </menu>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  data: Array,
  applyFilter: Function
})
...
```

Have anyone any idea?

Comment: Looks like you want to make `selects` reactive by returning it from a `computed`, but that does not work, `computed` only works with already reactive properties. You'll have to make `selects` reactive through `ref` of `reactive`.